# Graphviz and dot path

Tags: sql-server, graphviz

Im trying to use schemaspy to generate a mssql db schema.

I have the following:

Schemaspy_5.0.0
Graphviz2-38
jtds-1.3.1 as mssql driver
SchemaspyGUI

after clic start the schema on schemaspy, this is the command schemaspGUI generates:

```
java -jar "C:\Esquema\schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar" -dp "C:\Esquema\jtds-1.3.1-dist\jtds-
1.3.1.jar" -t mssql-jtds -db database -all  -host LOCAL.LOCALHOST -port 1433 -u genaro 
-connprops "C:\Esquema\properties\mssql-jtds.properties" -o "C:\Esquema\database" -hq
```

It displays this message:

```
Failed to query Graphviz version information
with: dot -V
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dot": CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no 
puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

In the graphviz download page says that you must add dot to your path, but after a long search i cant figure out how to add it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows. Use either the method in the question (for a permanent change) or in the highest-voted answer (for a temporary change).

Comment: Thanks for your help, the method in the question is the one I used.

Answer (score 0):

Since my PATH is already polluted enough, I tried hacking the SchemaSpyGUI text boxes to inject the -gv parameter into the schemaspy command line.

On the Output Options tab, in the Output Directory textbox, end the output path with a " and a space, then -gv "C:\Path\To\Graphviz\NotTheBinFolder
and no closing ", because this is added by SchemaSpyGUI

Like so:

[image]